# How can I run onclick function on python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How can I run `onclick` on selected row?
To run a javascript `onClick` event with python, 
I tried something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('fastforward').click()
```

[page code on site (selected row)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZuAS.jpg)

or another exemple: (outer HTML)

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function') {jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_id31'),{'j_id31:j_id35':'j_id31:j_id35'},'');}return false" class="sf-with-ul">Selection One</a>


.sf-menu > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) (Unique selector code)
```

Comment: Do you want to click on `tr` or `td` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click on `<td>`, try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(@onclick,"{'page': 'fastforward'}")]').click()
```

If you want to click on its parent `<tr>` element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(@onclick,"{'page': 'fastforward'}")]/parent::tr').click()
```

**UPDATE**

To click "Next" button on pagination panel, try to use this line:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[text()="»"]').click()
```

Let me know if any exceptions occurs

Comment: i think that on "td" element, that a found reference to button image (red arrow on image), i'm using python 2.7 with selinium, o tryed with code:

Comment: i tried first line <td> but, Python not run, report a error on ` 'page' ` , invalid syntax , any idea?      and about second code `<a href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function') {jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_id31'),{'j_id31:j_id35':'j_id31:j_id35'},'');}return false" class="sf-with-ul">Selection One</a>
 `  , i use 'j_id31:j_id35':'j_id31:j_id35' as reference ?  thanks

Comment: To get rid of `invalid syntax` error in first code `\ `should be applied to embedded strings like follow: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(@onclick,"{\'page\': \'fastforward\'}")]').click()`

Comment: perfect ! it´s working,  in the middle of tests my firefox update to 47 and no work anymore, i install v46 and everthing ok again... thanks very much !  God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use following xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Put Text Of TD')]").click()
```